# Firemonkey Android get battery level

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

I got a function:

```
function BatteryPercent(const aContext: JContext): Integer;
var
  filter: JIntentFilter;
  battery: JIntent;
  level, scale: Integer;
begin
  filter := TJIntentFilter.Create;
  filter.addAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);

  battery := aContext.registerReceiver(NIL, filter);
  level := battery.getIntExtra(StringToJString('level'), -1);
  scale := battery.getIntExtra(StringToJString('scale'), -1);

  result := (100 * level) div scale;
end;
```

But what should I pass as `aContext` param?

I need to get battery life every minute and save it to memo...

Comment: Use MainActivity global variable (FMX.Platform.Android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read this article on my Blog; "[Battery Information (Android - XE5)](http://neftali.clubdelphi.com/?p=3157)".
The original Article is in Spanish, but you can try automatic translation (on right of page).

You can read the code and download the sample project (with sources).

The code I use is similar to this:

```
  // Contexto
  myContext := SharedActivityContext;

  // Creamos y Configuramos el Intent
  filter := TJIntentFilter.Create;
  // Asociamos la ACTION que queremos capturar
  filter.addAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
  // lo registramos
  intentBatt := myContext.registerReceiver(nil, filter);
```

[image]

Regards.

Comment: `SharedActivityContext` is undefined in XE6

Comment: Use TAndroidHelper.Context instead.